# gfortran write does not wrap after each line

Tags: eclipse, fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I am running the following commands as part of a larger program, using gfortran as a compiler in the Eclipse IDE:

`Open(unit = 11, file = 'RateResult.txt', status = 'unknown')
 Write (11,fmt='(A)',advance="yes") "Time(days) Flow Rate(bpd)"
 Write (11, fmt="(F10.3)",advance="no") TotalTime
 Write (11, fmt="(F10.3)",advance="yes") qinj`

---

However, when I compile and run, the second and fourth lines do not cause the line wrapping.

Previously, when using the Intel FORTRAN compiler, I did not include the "advance" argument, and the lines wrapped by default.

Could anyone let me know what is causing this error?

Thank you!

Comment: Which compiler version are you using and how are TotalTime and qinj declared? I am unable to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I know it's not answering your question, but if you wanted you could just write both values using the same call: `write(11, fmt="(*(f10.3))") TotalTime, qinj`.

Comment: Maybe you could give a minimal compilable code which exhibits your issue. See [mcve]

Comment: I am using GNU Fortran 6.3.0. I will send a minimal example shortly.

Comment: Below is a minimal example (Sorry for the awful formatting). I saved it as an f90 file and compiled and executed in the command line. I expect a table-like output, but all the output is on one line.

`program WriteExample
    implicit none

    Open(unit = 1, file = 'Output.txt', status = 'unknown')

    Write (1,fmt='(A)',advance="yes") "Time(days) Flow Rate(bpd)"
    Write (1, fmt="(F10.3)",advance="no") 1.0
    Write (1, fmt="(F10.3)",advance="yes") 100.0
    Write (1, fmt="(F10.3)",advance="no") 2.0
    Write (1, fmt="(F10.3)",advance="yes") 200.0

end program WriteExample`

Comment: I looked a little more and I found that although Notepad does not wrap lines, the lines wrap when I used Notepad ++, import into Excel, or manipulate with Python. So this seems to be an issue with Notepad. Thanks so much for the help!